# Colour dynamic wave based on amplitude

Tags: rendering, animation, materials

I'm trying to make an animation of a wave propagating where the colour of the wave changes based on its height.

Something like this:

[image]

I'm using the dynamic waves tool to generate the wave. I managed to create the effect I'm looking for with a View Z Depth input node and a color ramp, but that doesn't seem to show up when I render and only works when viewed from directly overhead.

Comment: Why are you using z-depth? What does your base surface looks like?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Z depth is distance from the camera. To get Z world position, use the "Geometry" shader node to get the position of the surface. This might help you with a shader for a flat object with displacement. See this for an example https://youtu.be/rmUfNw6luWI.